# How do I set the background of a data cell in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, background, styling

I am trying to set the background image of each data cell to an image. When I use the method shown below, I only get the top left corner of the photo.

As shown below, I am simply setting the background of each data cell to the image I chose; however, I assume that there is more styling that needs to be done to the class. Does anyone know what that would be?

```css
.example {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg");
}
```

```html
<table class="example">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p> ONE </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p> TWO </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can add `background-size:cover;` to your `example` class,  `object-fit: cover;` won't work for tables, btw you don't have to use `example` class in `td` element as @thingEvery said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want the images in the cells, you've got to select the `td` in your css. Then, use `background-size` to determine how the image is sized.

```css
.example td {
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<table class="example">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p> ONE </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p> TWO </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```